# Persistent Window Placement?

Tags: unity, window

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Open application in specific workspace](https://askubuntu.com/questions/89946/open-application-in-specific-workspace)

Does anyone know a way of keeping windows in the place you put them, between shutting down and logging back on again, rather where the load themselves?

At the moment whenever I boot up, Chrome always leaves a gap where the (auto-hidden) launcher is, and other windows load with the toolbar underneath the top-panel, and others with half the window below my screen?

Thanks!