# Open application in specific workspace

Tags: workspaces, window, window-management

I would like to have some applications always appear in a specific workspace. For example: I would like my mp3 player on the bottom left workspace, and terminal application on the bottom right one;

I am new to Ubuntu, so tried using `wmctrl` but it looks to me as desktop wall works by creating one big desktop and then splitting it up into 4 pieces.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

**Note: This answer was written for systems running the Compiz window manager (default in Ubuntu 7.04 to 17.04). For versions of Ubuntu using Gnome Shell see this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1077158/22537)**.

1. Install compizconfig-settings-manager:

   ```
   sudo apt install compizconfig-settings-manager
   ```
2. Go to Window Management -> Place Windows -> Fixed Window Placement
3. Under Windows with fixed viewport  click on **new**

   - `class=NameOfYourProgram` (Here the spelling is important. Better use the green plus sign and "Grab" this parameter in the resulting window)
   - Position : {1,1}top left; {1,2}bottom left, ...
   - example opens Gnome-terminal in bottom right workspace :
     [image]

More information on [wiki.compiz.org](http://wiki.compiz.org/Plugins/Place)

Comment: It works so far - but how can i make unity to automatically switch to the specified workspace when opening the program? Right now I always how to manually switch to the workspace the program has been opened in.

Comment: @gucki you could edit the .desktop file to launch the program, then switch.

Comment: does anyone know why this doesn't work for skype?

Comment: This didn*t work for me on 14.04

Comment: does anyone know why this doesn't work for steam or discord? (works on chrome tho)

Comment: outdated solution

Comment: This doesn't address the OP's question which was to start an application in a specific workspace, probably one you're not currently in. I'd like to know how to do this using MATE and Compiz as well as being able to start an app in all workspaces.

Answer (score 11):

Install the Gnome extension ["Auto Move Windows"](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/16/auto-move-windows/).

1. The package should come with Ubuntu, otherwise `sudo apt-get install gnome-tweak-tool`
2. Open Tweaks
3. Go to Extensions
4. Configure and Activate Auto Move Windows

Comment: Using `Auto Move Windows` still works in 19.04, you just need to install it from Ubuntu Software because it is no more available inside `gnome-tweak-tool`

Comment: This is already something but when connecting/disconnecting an external monitor it still scrambles windows all over workspaces

Answer (score 6):

[Devilspie](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Devilspie) does a wonderful job of controlling how your windows launch, no matter what.

Comment: I'll try this in the morning, but is this the same in Compiz (through CCSM) under place windows? As that didn't work when I first tried it.

Comment: Works now! Although '0' on the X axis isn't completely on the left...

Comment: I'd love an example of how to make it open on a specific space