# Workspace switcher moves my terminal windows around

Tags: workspaces

I have 4 workspaces that I use (2x2 grid). I'm experiencing very odd and unpredictable behavior: I find that my terminal windows seem to get moved around (usually up or down one workspace.) Half the time they end up being halfway between the two workspaces. This happens very frequently but I don't know if anything I do causes it.

Is this a known issue, and can I do anything about it?

Comment: maybe you wanna read http://askubuntu.com/questions/89946/open-application-in-specific-workspace

Comment: The problem is that the windows move around while open and switching between workspaces, even though I don't move them.