# How to start new applications in a new workspace (GNOME shell)?

Tags: gnome-shell, workspaces, window, window-management

What I really like about GNOME shell is that the user can easily place different applications in different workspaces, thus giving each application the entire desktop. The pain in that is that the user has to manually switch the applications between workspaces.

There is an extension that forces specific applications to be opened in predesignated workspaces; for example, Firefox would start at workspace 4, Banshee at workspace 3, etc. But the drawback of that is that if the user is working in workspace one and wants to start Firefox, he/she would have 2 empty workspaces between 1 and 4. Not only that but also programs that aren't configured would still open in the current workspace.

Is there an extension or a script that forces new applications to start in the last open workspace (the empty one), no matter how many workspaces are open?

Comment: [This answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1077158/480481) is specifically for GNOME shell.

Answer (score 2):

Check out this extension: https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/16/auto-move-windows/. Works with GS 3.4+