# Unity: Have a window that is always on specific workspaces?

Tags: unity, multiple-monitors, workspaces

I have two monitors and 4 workspaces configured in unity (2 monitor on each workspace).
I do development using IntelliJ IDE on server side and hybrid mobile app frontend so I often have two instances of the IDE open on different workspace on left monitor and browser for testing on the right like

workspace 1 monitor 1: IDE with server code opened

workspace 1 monitor 2: browser that is serviced from the server code.

workspace 2 monitor 1: IDE with hybrid browser app code open

workspace 2 monitor 2: browser with browser app

Now sometimes I would drag the IDE on server code to be side by side with the browser app IDE so I can check on some code and stuff.

So My question is. Is it possible to have a window to be 'Always Visible' on only certain workspace? so I have say server code IDE always visible on monitor 2 of workspace 1 and workspace 3 and Browser app IDE always visible on monitor 1 of workspace 2 and 3?

workspace 1 monitor 1: browser that is serviced from the server code.

workspace 1 monitor 2: IDE with server code opened (pinned)

workspace 2 monitor 1: IDE with hybrid browser app code open (pinned)

workspace 2 monitor 2: browser with browser app

workspace 3 monitor 1: IDE with hybrid browser app code open (pinned)

workspace 3 monitor 2: IDE with server code opened (pinned)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Open application in specific workspace](http://askubuntu.com/questions/89946/open-application-in-specific-workspace)