# How can I force terminal to always open in a specific desktop, regardless of which one I'm in when I press the shortcut

Tags: command-line, lubuntu, .desktop

Basically the title. Using Lubuntu 14.04.

Use case: I have two desktops, I'm in #1, I press <kbd>Ctl</kbd> <kbd>Alt</kbd> <kbd>T</kbd> , it opens in Desktop 2. I'm in #2, press <kbd>Ctl</kbd> <kbd>Alt</kbd> <kbd>T</kbd>  it opens in Desktop 2.

Answer (score 1):

I used compizconfig-settings-manager to open specific programs in a specific workspace. You can refer to [the answer here](https://askubuntu.com/a/90014/387996).

However this just opens the terminal and i have to move to that work space to get to the terminal, it doesn’t do that automatically.

Comment: That's what the OP asked.  Just to place it there.  Not move to thet desktop automatically...

Answer (score 0):

You may edit `~/.config/openbox/lubuntu-rc.xml` to do what you want.

- Back up the file for safety
- Open it in a plain text editor (such as nano or leafpad)
- Scroll down to the end of the file. Notice that the second last line is `</applications>`

Just above the second last line, paste the following:

```
<application name="lxterminal">  
  <desktop>2</desktop>  
</application>
```

Save the file and run `openbox --reconfigure` to make the change take effect immediately.

Now, whenever you access lxterminal via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>, lxterminal will open on Desktop 2 irrespective of which desktop you're currently on.