# Problem with startup applications and workspaces in Xubuntu

Tags: xubuntu, workspaces

How can I add a specific applications to their respective workspaces in Xubuntu. I did add some application in application startup, But there is no information to which workspace it will get assigned. By far all are getting executed in workspace 1.
Is their any tweak for Xubuntu??
Is their any script were i can specify the workspace number to the cmd application??

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Open application in specific workspace](https://askubuntu.com/questions/89946/open-application-in-specific-workspace)

Comment: There is no build in solution: you need extra tools. Ses the answers in the duplicate question. For Xubuntu, you will need to work with devilspie or devilspie2.

Answer (score 0):

Linux desktops generally have no build-in approach to control in which workspace a launched application will appear. Options to achieve that [depend on your desktop environment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/89946/open-application-in-specific-workspace/1077158#1077158).

One tool that works on any desktop running on Xorg is **devilspie** and its successor, `devilspie2`, both old tools that may lack maintenance, have scarce documentation, but they do the job well.

I use `devilspie2` myself. It takes a little bit learning to set it up, but once setup, you quickly forget about it. [A tutorial](https://www.linux-magazine.com/Issues/2017/205/Tutorial-Devilspie2) can help you understand quickly how it works.

It boils down to having a good configuration file, and have the `devilspie2` executable autostart when you log on. With rules, you can have newly created windows that match the given criteria manipulated, including moving them to a specific workspace. For example, the following rule, taken from the linked tutorial, will have windows from LibreOffice 5.4 start on workspace 2:

```
if (get_application_name() == "LibreOffice 5.4") then
  set_window_workspace(2);
end
```

You can run **compiz** on Xubuntu, so provided you want to switch to another window manager than the default, the [accepted answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/89946/open-application-in-specific-workspace/1077158#1077158) in the linked question could also be applicable for you.